# On button click create dynamic drop down lists with unique id's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, unique-id

I want to create multiple dynamic drop down lists on click of a button..
Each added drop down list should have a unique I'd.

I have a piece of code which creates multiple drop down list but I don't know how to add code for creating unique IDs for ddls..

Here is my code which creates ddls:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group" id="containerOWL">
// I want to add dynamic drop down list here
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 32px;">
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="OW_LO_LW()" style="margin: 0 0 0 15px;">+ Add OWL/LO/LW</a>
</div>

function OW_LO_LW() {
var drop_list = '<select class="form-control">';
drop_list += '<option selected disabled >Select</option>';
drop_list += '<option >FL</option>';
drop_list += '<option >GA</option>';
drop_list += '<option >AL</option>';
drop_list += '</select>';
$("#containerOWL").append(drop_list);
}
```

Thank you ☺️

Comment: You seem to have omitted some elements from your HTML. In addition, you have a typo when declaring your function. The `function` keyword should be lowercase.

Comment: I have updated the code, so currently onclick="OW_LO_LW()" it is creating multiple DDl I want to add code to add unique ID's for each DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `data attribute` to containerOWL like this `data-number=0`

Now on function call you can simply get that number and increase it by one and give that value to that select id. And finally increase that data attribute value.

complete code:

```
function OW_LO_LW() {
    containerOWL = $("#containerOWL")

    const currValue = containerOWL.data("number")
    const nextValue = currValue + 1

    var drop_list = `<select id="${nextValue}" class="form-control">`;
    drop_list += '<option selected disabled >Select</option>';
    drop_list += '<option >FL</option>';
    drop_list += '<option >GA</option>';
    drop_list += '<option >AL</option>';
    drop_list += '</select>';
    containerOWL.append(drop_list);

    containerOWL.data("number", nextValue)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting, your code is helping me. Can you let me know the script for data-number because currently it's taking NaN.

Comment: oh it's pretty simple, `<div class="form-group" id="containerOWL" data-number=0>` Please accept the answer if it solve your issue. Thanks